# Free program to manage Sharepoint site permissions for lots of sites and lots of users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a lot of Sharepoint sites that I need to setup permissions on.  Manually opening each site and adding users takes a lot of time.  It is also tedious as these users are usually the same ones across many (but not all) of the sites.

Is there a way to group manage these sites (without inherited permissions)?

I have seen a few programs out there that do it, but they are not free.  Normally that would not be too much of a problem, but my company has put out a purchasing freeze.  So I have no hope of buying any tools for this.

Before I spend all that time manually updating each site, I thought I would see if there is a free tool out there that helps me do this.

Comment: Have you looked at using PowerShell? Is there something it didn't provide or you didn't like that can help in answering your questions?

Comment: @Goyuix - I have not looked at using PowerShell.  Does it have a some "Group Management" type commands that will allow me to update permissions to more than one site at a time?  (Do you have a link to something about this that I can read up on?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to help automate this, you may want to get started with the instructional video here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518673

To help get you started - a simple script like this to add a user to a site:

```
New-SPUser -UserAlias "DOMAIN\Goyuix" -Web "http://localhost" -Group "Team Site Owners"
```

You can also remove users easily enough:

```
Remove-SPUser "DOMAIN\Goyuix" -Web "http://localhost"
```

You may also find these getting started instructions helpful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx